# How to allocate a variably sized object with correct alignment using an Allocator?

Tags: c++, memory-management, alignment, allocator

Say I have the following object that I want to be variably sized:

```
struct VarSized {
    std::array<int, 500> fixedHeader;
    std::byte extraMemory[]; // variably sized part
}
```

How can I allocate such an object *with correct alignment* using an [Allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator)? E.g., how would I implement this method:

```
// Allocates a `VarSized` with `extraMemory` being `numExtraBytes` large.
template<typename Allocator>
VarSized* allocateVarSized(size_t numExtraBytes, Allocator alloc = Allocator()) {
  // ... ?
}
```

Option1:
I could either rebind the allocator to `VarSized`, but then I cannot pick the number of extra bytes, as the allocated object needs to be a multiple of the size of `VarSized`. To show the problem, I have chosen `VarSized` to be very large in this example (2000 bytes). Thus, if someone requested this object with one extra byte, I would need to allocate 4000 instead of 2001 bytes in this example, which would be a waste.

Option 2:
Or I rebind the allocator to `std::byte`, but then I am not guaranteed to get an object that is correctly aligned for the `int`s, as the `alignof(std::byte)` is 1. I can pray that people will always use this methods with allocators that always align to 4 bytes at least, but otherwise my code would be wrong. So this is not really an option.

```
// Option 1: Unable to choose the number of extra bytes correctly
template<typename Allocator>
VarSized* allocateVarSized1(size_t numExtraBytes, Allocator alloc = Allocator()) {
   using A = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<VarSized>;
   A a(alloc);
   return a.allocate(/* unable to put the numExtraBytes here :( */);
}

// Option 2: Possible incorrect alignment
template<typename Allocator>
VarSized* allocateVarSized2(size_t numExtraBytes, Allocator alloc = Allocator()) {
   using A = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<std::byte>;
   A a(alloc);
   /* May be incorrectly aligned :( */
   return reinterpret_cast<VarSized*>(a.allocate(sizeof(VarSized) + numExtraBytes));
}
```

The best solution I see so far is using the first option and always round up the number of extra bytes to a be a multiple of `sizeof(VarSized)`. This could allocate way too much memory in this example.

Is there no possibility to use an allocator to allocate a variably sized object with correct alignment? I would need a method where I can specify the allocation size and the alignment explicitly, but allocators don't seem to provide such a method.

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing as "variably sized objects" in C++. The storage for all objects of some type `T` has the very same size (`sizeof(T)`). Therefore, you cannot have two objects of type `VarSized` having different sizes of their memory representations.

Comment: @DanielLangr: Well, true. Then phrase it differently: I want a contiguous area of memory, which starts with a well-aligned VarSize object and is guaranteed to have `extraBytes` more bytes behind it. Or phrase it even differently. I guess there is some way to phrase it so it is correct C++ :).

Comment: Then, allocate this memory dynamically with `operator new` (possibly the overload that supports alignment specification if `VarSize` is overaligned). And, provide the size of `VarSize` + the number of extra bytes. Of course, you need to initialize that `VarSize` object then there (with placement new or `std::construct_at`).

Comment: @DanielLangr then I would lose custom allocator support.

Comment: Ok, you can as well allocate that memory with the `allocate` member function of some allocator, instead of with `operator new`.

Comment: Why do you think you need to align `VarSized` as 500*`int`s and not simply as an `int`?

Comment: @YSC True, I could `rebind<std::aligned_storage<alignof(VarSize),alignof(VarSize)>`. I guess that's my best bet so far. If there is no better way, feel free to add as an answer.

Comment: You mean `std::aligned_storage<alignof(VarSize), alignof(int)>`?

Comment: That should be the same, but my definition would be more robust and work for any defintion of `VarSize` I guess.